# Connect to PostgreSQL in R with RODBC

Tags: r, postgresql, rodbc

I want to use PostgreSQL in R. To connect, I want to use RODBC, as it can be used more universally than the package RPostgreSQL (which works just fine for me).

Using the command below, which is suggested by people on some forums, the Console simply does nothing but show an empty command line, no error message. When pressing escape, it tells me to use warnings() to see all 50 warnings.

```
con <- odbcDriverConnect('driver = {PostgreSQL}; user=tobiaspk1; host=localhost; port=5432; dbname=db_tobi; trusted_connection = true')
```

I use PostgreSQL 9.5.3

Thank you!

Comment: Did you use the command? What warnings were produced?

Comment: The line is not designed to output anything. If no error emerged on console, then you successfully connected. Check if you can run any `sqlQuery()`.

Comment: Do note: unlike other DB APIs, RODBC requires a prior install (outside of R) of the corrrespoding odbc compliant driver for your RDBMS, here being Postgres. R will not install this for you. And this same odbc driver can be used elsewhere outside R: Python, PHP, even Excel VBA. Hence the universality.

Comment: Yet native drivers will generally be faster than ODBC.